# Conditional highlighting of booleans in Apple Numbers

Tags: numbers

Is it possible to do conditional highlighting of booleans in Apple Numbers?

I want to highlight `TRUE` values one way, and `FALSE` values another, but booleans don't seem to be supported - only numbers, text, dates, durations and blank:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried using "Numbers" => "equal to" but it didn't seem to accept my attempt at doing "equal to" `FALSE`.

I'm currently using Numbers 3.5.3.

One possible, hacky, workaround would be to change them from booleans to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Apple has implemented this functionality natively now (at least on Numbers 11.2) so that no language-dependent workaround is needed.

When setting up a **Highlighting Rule**, choose [image: Cell icon] **Cell** as type, and there you will find the **"Is true""Is false"** rules

Answer (score 2):

A boolean in Numbers seems to be represented internally as a String already. Setting "text is TRUE" and "text is FALSE" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The OP does not specify how `TRUE` or `FALSE` are represented in the cell, but as was stated in [another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/224444/120171), using **text is** rule will work.  This also works for checkboxes, they resolve to `TRUE` and `FALSE` as well.

- Text is TRUE add formatting
- Text is FALSE add other formatting

This works for the result of a formula returning the text `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  If one is using numbers for Booleans, i.e.: `0` or not `0` then use a **number** rule.

- Number is equal to 0 [zero representing FALSE] add formatting
- Number is not equal to 0 [in the case of any number is TRUE] other formatting

#### See screenshots for examples.

---

[image: Conditional formatting for text]

[image: Conditional formatting for numbers]

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, these answers are really bad advices if you happen to collaborate with other who have theirs macs not in the same language (so does Numbers).
What I mean is if you edit the document in English and then hand it over to someone else who happens to have - let's say - Italian as default language, it will fail.

The only way I made it work was to introduce additional, hidden column that will explicitly convert value from the boolean column into 0/1 and filter by that hidden column.